# async await or Promise not returning on stream event

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, knex.js

I have the following function which returns a Promise where the function argument is an async function:

```
  createObjectFrom(record) {
    const self = this;
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let obj = {};

      for(let i = 0, l = self.opts.transformers.length; i < l; i++) {
        let transformer = self.opts.transformers[i];

        const headerIndex = findIndex(self.headers, (header) => {
          return header === transformer.column;
        });

        let csvValue = record[headerIndex];

        const lookUp = transformer.options.lookUp;

        const whereClause = {};

        whereClause[lookUp.column] = csvValue;

        console.log('before await');

        const result = await self.knex(lookUp.table).where(whereClause).select(lookUp.scalar);

        console.dir(result);

        obj[transformer.field] = result[0][lookUp.scalar];
      }

      return resolve(obj);
    });
  }
```

If I call the function like this from at test, it all executes correctly:

```
  it('creates the transformed object', async () => {
    const csvRecord = ['PREMIER', '07/11/1998', manager, 'Liverpool', 'Wimbledon', 0, 1, 'A', 0, 1, 'A'];

    const record = await transformer.createObjectFrom(csvRecord);

    expect(record.division).to.equal('PREMIER');
  }
```

But when calling the `createObjectFrom` function during a [readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable) event which is raised from a stream created from [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse):

```
  onReadable() {
    let record = this.parser.read();

    if (record === null) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.parser.count <= 1) {
      this.headers = record;
    } else {
      const recordPromises = this.createObjectFrom(record);
      this.recordPromises.push( newRecord );
    }
  }
```

THe code gets to the `console.log` statement below in `createObjectFrom`

```
  console.log('before here');
  const result = await self.knex(lookUp.table).where(whereClause).select(lookUp.scalar);
  console.dir(result);
```

But does not get to the `console.dir` statement below as the Promise does not seem to resolve.

If I call `createObjectFrom` from a test outside of the stream processing then it resolves correctly.

I have also tried refactoring async await out of this to just return a promise but it is still broke.

```
If I console.dir the promises on the [end][3] event of the stream they look like this:

[ Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined } ]
```

I have [this](https://github.com/dagda1/knex-csv-transformer) repo which has the source code and a failing test.

I am baffled as to what is going on.

The following test also passes so it is definitely something to do with the stream:

```
  it('creates the transformed object', async () => {
    const csvRecords = [
      ['PREMIER', '07/11/1998', manager, 'Liverpool', 'Wimbledon', 0, 1, 'A', 0, 1, 'A'],
      ['PREMIER', '11/11/1998', manager, 'QPR', 'Sunderland',3,3, 'Sunderland',0,0,'Sunderland'],
      ['PREMIER', '14/11/1998', manager, 'Southampton', 'Liverpool', 3, 3, 'D', 0, 0, 'D']
    ];

    for(var i = 0, l = csvRecords.length; i < l; i++) {
      const csvRecord = csvRecords[i];

      const record = await transformer.createObjectFrom(csvRecord);

      expect(record.division).to.equal('PREMIER');

      expect(record.manager_id).to.equal(manager_id);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what you are missing but we are missing a fiddle

Comment: I don't see any particular reason for browser to not support this script. `await` could be transformed with babel to es6 generators (or whatever they use), which should be enough for modern chrome / firefox browsers

Comment: You should try, otherwise most likely you won't receive any help... The question is too specific and can be solved either with a random guess (not that high probability) or debugging only.

Comment: please, calm down. I am trying to help you. But if you wish - go on with a question with no answers.

Comment: have you ever tried to replace the `self.knex(...)` part with `Promise.resolve('test');` to be 100% sure it's not your knex part that has a problem?

Comment: Making the executor function of the Promise constructor async (`return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) ...)`) is an antipattern and can cause exceptions to get swallowed.

Comment: I just tried that and Promise.resolve works so it is definitely something to do with knex

Comment: @robertklep I refactored the code to use promises in this branch https://github.com/dagda1/knex-csv-transformer/blob/promise/src/knex-csv-transformer.js#L191 and the same thing happens, the promise never resolves

Comment: @dagda1 if `self.knex()` already returns a promise, why does it get wrapped with a `new Promise()` again? You're also not catching any errors from the calls to `self.knex()` (they _will_ get swallowed).

Comment: Because it does other stuff apart depending on the first result from knex https://github.com/dagda1/knex-csv-transformer/blob/promise/src/knex-csv-transformer.js#L203

Comment: @robertklep I refactored to this https://gist.github.com/dagda1/e39073f6669bf4201116d101f5be8016 and the promise never resolves

Comment: @dagda1 and the promise also doesn't get rejected?

Comment: @robertklep nope, I think I am just going to gather the csv results and do the processing outside of the stream.  There seems to be something out of my sight going on here.

Comment: OMG, what an arse, I think it was because I was not returning the promise from the test.  When testing promises with mocha, you need to return the promise from the ```it``` function.  If you do this it all works.  What a fool!

Answer (score 2):

why you don't change your code like this:

```
createObjectFrom: async (record) => {
    const self = this;
    // return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let obj = {};

      for(let i = 0, l = self.opts.transformers.length; i < l; i++) {
        let transformer = self.opts.transformers[i];

        const headerIndex = findIndex(self.headers, (header) => {
          return header === transformer.column;
        });

        let csvValue = record[headerIndex];

        const lookUp = transformer.options.lookUp;

        const whereClause = {};

        whereClause[lookUp.column] = csvValue;

        console.log('before await');

        const result = await self.knex(lookUp.table).where(whereClause).select(lookUp.scalar);

        console.dir(result);

        obj[transformer.field] = result[0][lookUp.scalar];
      }
      return obj;
      // return resolve(obj);
    // });
  }
```

Comment: Same deal, execution never returns after the first await call

Comment: I think there may be some problem there `self.knex(lookUp.table).where(whereClause).select(lookUp.scalar);`

Comment: The code works when called from the test I detailed above

Comment: I see what  the code does is find something in DB, please make sure it return a promise.

Comment: and I will repeat again, it works from the test and it does return a promise

Comment: @dagda1 did you ever modify your test to include iteration? the self.knex promise not resolving seems to pretty clearly point to it not resolving as being the problem...

Comment: yes, for sure, how would I alter the test for iteration.  You mean just a for loop?

Comment: right, add back parts of the code until it stops working again. if it breaks with iteration, step through each iteration one by one to see which one is failing, then isolate that step to see why.

Comment: It works fine from a loop in a test, this passes https://gist.github.com/dagda1/697cae1e04e53116ecb937a708b70fec

Comment: @KevinB my guess is that it's actually getting rejected, and the exception is  either not handled, or it gets swallowed for some reason. Would be easy to test by wrapping the `self.knex()` call with a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 2):

OMG, what an arse, it was because I was not returning the promise from the test.  When testing promises with mocha, you need to return the promise from the `it` function.  If you do this it all works.  What a fool!

So if I change the test to this:

```
  describe('transformer', () => {
    it('transforms the data and imports the csv file', () => {

      const ignoreIf = (data) => data[3] !== 'Liverpool' && data[4] !== 'Liverpool';
      const opts = { table: 'results', file: __dirname + '/fixtures/test.csv', encoding: 'utf8', transformers, ignoreIf: ignoreIf };

      const f = seeder(opts)(knex, Promise);

      return f.then((results) => {
        console.dir(results);
      });
    });
```

I `return f` and all is good now.